# Find Substring at Index then retrieve number following

Tags: c#

I have this string value

> The Quick Brown Fox VOL 5 Jumped Over 10 Fences'

I need to find the next number immediately after some input, like "VOL". There will be a space between my input and the number.

In this example, I need to return 5. If I passed in "Over" I would get 10.

How do I do that?

Comment: Use a regex like `VOL\w*(\d+)` to find and capture the number.

Comment: There is a space between `VOL` and `5` in your example. Is this always the case, or can there be other things in between?

Comment: @juharr that wont work if there's a space between `VOL 5`... Adding `sw*` works. `VOL\s{1}+(\d+)` works just fine and grab the first group which will be your number.

Comment: There is always a space in between.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Yeah I should have done \s instead of \w

Comment: I guess another condition is that the vol could also be two digits sometimes. So VOL 5, VOL 10 etc.

Comment: What is the metric for "best way"? Shortest code? Most robust? Easiest to maintain? Fewest memory accesses?

Comment: You could not save the number into a string in the first place, and you will always have it as a int type so that you don't need to do any string manipulation.

Comment: `int number = input.Contains("VOL") ? int.Parse(new string(input.Substring(input.IndexOf("VOL")).SkipWhile(c => !char.IsDigit(c)).TakeWhile(char.IsDigit).ToArray())) : someDefault;`

Comment: To be honest, there's numerous ways to accomplish this, answers are more than likely going to be opinionated. What's the metric for "best way" as already mentioned by @HABO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is a great tool for this sort of thing. The specific regex you use can depend on things like whether VOL always has a space before it, whether "numbers" can have commas or decimals, etc., but this can give you an idea:

```
IEnumerable<string> volValues = Regex.Matches("The Quick Brown Fox VOL 5 Jumped Over 10 Fences", @"VOL\s*(\d+)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);
```

If you want to be able to change the preceding value (e.g. `"VOL"`), you can abstract that out, but be sure to escape it for correctness. That might look something like this:

```
var precedingText = "VOL";
var input = "The Quick Brown Fox VOL 5 Jumped Over 10 Fences";
List<int> integersAfterPrecedingText = Regex.Matches(input, @$"{Regex.Escape(precedingText)}\s+(\d+)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .Select(int.Parse)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: A suggestion: pass "VOL" as a variable and regex escape it.

Comment: @gunr2171: Sounds good. Check out my update.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  string pattern = @"(?<=VOL *)\d+";
  string input = "The Quick Brown Fox VOL 533 Jumped Over 10 Fences";
  Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
  if (m.Success)
     Console.WriteLine("Found '{0}' at position {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
```

Note: .Net Regex supports look behind with non fixed width.

Comment: IMHO, the look-around is overkill in the regex pattern.

Comment: @gunr2171 not only that, but that regex is wrong; maybe a type-o?

Comment: @gunr2171 `a quantifier in the lookbehind makes it non fixed width`...

Comment: `[^\d]*` matches anything that _is not a digit_. So not _just_ spaces. [This example](https://regexr.com/4pcui) shows that it's too greedy.

Comment: @Matt.G My point is that in the last example "The VOL null Over 10", it should not have found a match at all, because there are non-space characters between the target word and the next number. (Also the third example)

Comment: @gunr2171, I agree. I went with the assumption that we need to capture the first numeric characters anywhere after VOL. I have changed the regex accordingly

Answer (score -1):

There are numerous ways to do it, but here are some simple ways to do it (without `Regex`).

**First Approach**

```
    public static int GetValue(string text, string keyword)
    {

        var find = text.Substring(text.IndexOf(keyword) + keyword.Length);

        string _tempValue = string.Empty;

        for (int x = 0; x < find.Length; x++)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(find[x]) && x > 0)
                break;

            _tempValue += find[x];
        }

        if (int.TryParse(_tempValue.Trim(), out int number))
        {
            return number;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

**Second Approach**

```
public static int GetValue(string text, string keyword)
{
    var list = text.Split(' ').ToList();

    for (int x = 0; x < list.Count; x++)
    {
        if (list[x].Equals(keyword))
        {
            if (int.TryParse(list[x + 1], out int number))
            {
                return number;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

usage :

```
var number = GetValue("The Quick Brown Fox VOL 5 Jumped Over 10 Fences", "VOL");
```

The first approach will first get the index of the desired keyword, then it'll slice the first portion of the string, so using your example, if we use the keyword `VOL` on

```
The Quick Brown Fox VOL 5 Jumped Over 10 Fences'
```

it'll slice it to :

```
5 Jumped Over 10 Fences
```

then we use this part in a loop, to get the numbers, and the loop will break at the first character that is not a number (like space, letters ..etc).

The second approach similar idea, but it converts the string to list and splits it by spaces. So, each word will be stored separately. So, if `VOL` index = 4, then the next index (5) will store the number.

`int.TryParse` used for insurance to always get an `int`.

I tried to give you something to start with. The examples needs some work though, but it's just for demonstration purposes.